# npm ERR! is not a child of when trying to create binary for namespaced package

Tags: npm

I have a package with the following `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "@namespace/package",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "bin": {
        "@namespace/package": "bin/package",
        "package": "bin/package"
    },
    "publishConfig": {
        "access": "public"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "prepublishOnly": "npm run build"
    },
    "files": [
        "lib",
        "bin"
    ],
    "main": "lib/index.js",
    "license": "MIT",
    ...
}
```

I want my package to work as a cli, so I added "bin" entry in my `package.json`, but every now and then when running npm install or npm ci I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! /var/lib/teamcity/BuildAgents/dataui-qyp-02/work/c3e015ff769f8dfa/node_modules/.bin/package is not a child of /var/lib/teamcity/BuildAgents/dataui-qyp-02/work/c3e015ff769f8dfa/node_modules/.bin/@namespace
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently if you read the [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin) carefully it says that bin is map of executable name to executable path, thus having a `/` inside the executable name may not be such a good idea, so the fix is to remove the following line from `package.json`:

```
"@namespace/package": "bin/package",
```